# ¿Cuándo es apropiado lanzar un error y cuándo devolver un valor falso en una función auxiliar?

Tags: javascript, express, validationerror

¿Cuál es la mejor práctica respecto al manejo de errores en una función auxiliar: lanzar una excepción o devolver un valor falso? Hago la pregunta con el animo de entender cuando se debe preferir lanzar errores y cuando regresar un falso. Para ello, consideremos dos enfoques específicos:

Caso 1. Lanzar error en funcion auxiliar.
El metodo auxiliar checkEmailFormat() lanza un error cuando el formato del email es invalido.
validateEmail() captura el error en el bloque "catch" y lanza una nueva expecion con el valor de error.message proveniente de checkEmailFormat()

```
class ValidateInputsClass{
    
     checkEmailFormat(email){
        if(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)){
            return true
        }
         throw new Error('invalid email format')
         
       
    }

    
    validateEmail(email){
        try {
            if(this.checkEmailFormat(email)) return true
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message)
         //'invalid email format'
        }
       
        
    }

    
}

module.exports = ValidateInputsClass
```

Caso 2. La funcion auxiliar devuelve falso y la funcion que llama al auxiliar evalua y actua en consecuencia, ya sea lanzando una expecion o devolviendo falso.

```
class ValidateInputsClass{
    
     checkEmailFormat(email){
        return (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email))
           
     }
    
    validateEmail(email){
        try {
            if(this.checkEmailFormat(email)){
        return true
            }
        else{
        //return false
        //throw new Error('invalid email format')
             }
    
        } catch (error) {
            //throw new Error(error.message)
        
            
         
        }
       
        
    }

    
}

module.exports = ValidateInputsClass
```

Muchas gracias por sus opiniones.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta se basa totalmente en opiniones, por lo cuál terminará cerrada.

Comment: tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones ... lo ideal en ese caso seria apegarce a un standar si es que existe este tipo de enunciado en los framework/estadar

Comment: La pregunta no está basada en opiniones. SOes es un sitio que da preferencia a preguntas especificas, y en especifico esta pregunta presenta 2 casos bien puntuales y acotados, donde el primero claramente presenta una inconsistencia y es un mal código

Answer (score 0):

En general el uso de `Exception` para controlar el flujo del código tiene defensores y detractores. Yo estoy con los detractores, generar excepciones debería ser (tal como su nombre lo indica) un recurso excepcional, algo que no se pudo controlar, y siempre hay que tener en cuenta que lanzar una `Exception` tiene un gasto de recursos asociados.

Ahora bien, eso en un ámbito general, pero en lo particular de tu ejemplo no me cabe duda alguna que estas usando mal las excepciones (en ambos casos)

Tus funciones `checkEmailFormat` y `validateEmail` retornan:

- `true` si es valido
- `Error` en caso contrario

##### **¿Y `false`, cuando?**

Es como si fueras al almacén y preguntaras "¿Tiene pan?" y el vendedor te respondiera "Error"... Pero si es una pregunta de `si o no`!! Tu caso es lo mismo, el correo es valido (true) o no lo es (false), no hay más.

##### ¿Cuando podría valer lanzar una excepción?

Cuando tienes un tercer caso, por ejemplo tu validas el formato de tu correo y además debe ser único, para eso compruebas que si existe o no en la base de datos. Tus posibles retornos son `true` y `false`, *¿pero que pasa si no fue posible conectar con la base de datos?* Aquí tienes un tercer caso: el de `no se ha podido validar`, porque el correo no es que sea invalido (entonces retornar false no es del todo correcto), si no que no has podido completar la validación, y además es un caso excepcional que escapa el flujo normal.

No está demás señalar que lo anterior es solo un ejemplo, y que también es posible de resolver de otras formas; y por otro lado que también existen más casos de uso donde usar una Exception es valido